# Convert VB.NET event with multiple event arguments to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, event-handling, vb.net-to-c#

I'm in the process of transplanting a unit test written in VB.NET to the larger project written in C#. However, this little ditty has me looking for help:

```
Public Sub object_DataChange(ByVal TransactionID As Integer, _
                             ByVal NumItems As Integer, _
                             ByRef ClientHandles As System.Array, _
                             ByRef ItemValues As System.Array, _
                             ByRef Qualities As System.Array, _
                             ByRef TimeStamps As System.Array) _
                             Handles myObject.DataChange

    '' Does event code here
End Sub
```

What is the best way to convert this event? Also, is this a good instance to use `EventHandler<>` to consolidate my arguments into a structure?

Comment: Just a tip. If I'm not mistaken SharpDevelop has a feature to convert VB.net to C# code. So if you have a lot of code to convert, that might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you're actually demonstrating an event handler vs. an event. C# does not have the `Handles` clause notion that [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) has. Instead you must manually assign an event handler to an event like so:

```
myObject.DataChange += this.object_DataChange;
```

And correspondingly, when you're done with the event you should remove the handler like so:

```
myObject.DataChange -= this.object_DataChange;
```

The actual event handler can be translated as follows.

```
void object_DataChange(
    int TransactionID,
    int NumItems,
    ref System.Array ClientHandles,
    ref System.Array ItemValues,
    ref System.Array Quantities,
    ref System.Array TimeStamps) {
    ...
}
```